# How can I instance an object on either side of an object and not on all faces

Tags: geometry-nodes

How can I instance an object on these cubes, they are on a drawn curve?

My nodes setup is like this
[image: Node Setup]

My scene look like this
[image: scene setup]

I want to achieve a centipede looking thing
tysm

Comment: Either side? Define a side... Why have a cube with 6 sides then? Why not have 2 planes or 2 vertices...

Comment: you could use an index selection or a normal selection on the original cube [before instanced] (this a capture) then `realize instances` and use in the `mesh to poins` `selection`, or you could do it to the selection of the `mesh to points` [without realizing] 
 (sometime this works as if you were operating on the original cube before it was instanced)

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys I think he just means either side, like you can pick which side, the querent doesn't care which side, as long it's on one of the 6 sides :D